# Columns in List control of SSRS 2008

Tags: list, charts, ssrs-2008, multiple-columns

My SSRS 2008 report has a List control and a column chart in the List control. Dynamically charts are created fine. But all charts are created in 1 column only. I want the list control to span in 2 or more columns so that I see all the charts in minimal space.Is there any property or tweak for this?

This is how my report looks like
[image]

I want the second chart to appear on right side besides chart 1.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of how your report looks like? Why don't you just extend the width of the column that you are trying to see in more space?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Column Group as opposed to a Row Group with your List Control